# Arrays in a Backbone.js Model are essentially static?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

Why are arrays in a Backbone.js Model essentially static variables?

```
class exports.Content extends Backbone.Model
    tags: []
```

then if i make a few models:

```
contentA = new Content()
contentB = new Content()
```

and add one string to each models' array:

```
contentA.tags.push('hello')
contentB.tags.push('world')
```

they both end up with the same array:

```
contentB.tags // ['hello','world']
```

but if it's a string, then there is no problem:

```
contentA.name = "c1"
contentB.name = "c2"

contentA.name // "c1"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The short answer

When you call `extends` to define your object, you are passing the new object's configuration in as an object literal. Objects are passed by reference, and the `extends` function only passes a reference to the tags array in to the new type definition.

As noted by others, you can correct this by assigning `tags` to a function. This works because a function delays the evaluation of the `tags` until the object is instantiated. There's nothing native in JavaScript that does this, but it's Backbone itself that recognizes `tags` as a function or a value.

### The long answer

In spite of your code being in CoffeeScript, this comes down to a combination of a few things in JavaScript:

- There are no classes in JavaScript
- Object literals are evaluated immediately
- JavaScript objects are passed around by reference

In JavaScript, there are no classes. Period. CoffeeScript gives you the notion of a class, but in reality, it gets compiled down to JavaScript which has no classes.

You can have types and type definitions (constructor functions) but not classes. Backbone provides a class-like definition, that looks similar to Java's "extend" class-based inheritance. It's still just JavaScript, though, which has no classes.

What we have, instead, is an object literal being passed in to the `extends` method. It's as if you write this code:

`var config = {
  tags: []
}`

var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extends(config);

In this code, `config` is an object literal, or a hash, or a key/value pair, or an associative array. Whatever name you call it, it's the same basic idea. You end up with a `config` object that has a `tags` attribute. The value of `config.tags` is an empty array, `[]`, which is itself an object.

Which brings us back to the short answer:

When you call `extends` to define your object, you are passing the new object's configuration in as an object literal. Objects are passed by reference, and the `extends` function only passes a reference to the tags array in to the new type definition.

As noted by others, you can correct this by assigning `tags` to a function. This works because a function delays the evaluation of the `tags` until the object is instantiated. There's nothing native in JavaScript that does this, but it's Backbone itself that recognizes `tags` as a function or a value.

Answer (score 6):

"tags" is being declared on the Content.prototype - which is shared across all instances of Content. You probably need to use defaults instead: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults. However, it should be noted that you must use a function (instead of a hash) when defining defaults, otherwise you still run into the same problem when using types which are passed by reference (e.g. Array).

```js
var Content = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: function() { 
    return {
      tags: []
    };
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

benpickles is correct when it comes to Backbone models, and the way to do this in coffeescript in general is to initialize instance properties in the constructor:

```
class Foo
  constructor: ->
    @bar = []
```

Answer (score 0):

As Derick Bailey mentioned, pass by reference is the problem.  I solved the problem by cloning the Array (passing-by-value essentially):

```
var _events = window.active_model.get('events').slice(0);
_events.push({ key: "xxx", value: "yyy" });
window.active_field.set('events', _events);
```