# Backbone or JavaScript keeps model's state after constructor is called

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Every time I call "this.model = new Unidade();", this.model keeps some values of the last value stored in there.

this.model.id => turns to null, but others properties keep the values of the last model.

Model Source

```
window.Unidade = Backbone.Model.extend({

urlRoot : $urlPadrao + "cliente/externo/unidade",

defaults: { // setting defaults to null or "" 
},

initialize: function () {
    ... // Just initialize the validators methods    
},

getDefaults: function() {
    // returns the same values of defaults
    // since I can't get a "new" model
}

});
```

In my view:

```
this.model = new Unidade();
// this.model may be already populated... I'm trying to create a new one
// that's the problem, it keeps some values of the last one
// Shouldn't give me a new model populate with the defaults?
```

For the record I'm not messing with the prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get the source of this sorcery, somehow, backbone was getting these properties and setting then on the prototype of the model, thus making them static.
Mighty strange.

Comment: This is quite interesting. Could you post your model & view codes (and maybe everything that could be related)?

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well.  Did you find a workaround or at least some means of preventing backbone from treating them as static on the prototype?

Answer (score 0):

By any chance are these properties arrays?  I found that mine were essentially being treated as pass-by-reference due to what I found in this article :

[Arrays in a Backbone.js Model are essentially static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974354/arrays-in-a-backbone-js-model-are-essentially-static)

Comment: No, some properties weren't on the defaults, maybe this was the cause.
I have a function in the view that binds changes to input and set the value to the model, But wasn't using set function of the model...
this.model.get(values[0])[values[1]] = target.val()