# Backbone - View objects sharing reference to a class

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Came across the following issue today, wonder if it's already been documented or is a known pitfall. Essentially, instantiated views are maintaining a reference to the class property.

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/wx6v6/)

Though this is only occurring for the array - the number is not being referenced in the same way - perhaps because it is a primitive.

Here's the code also:

```
var Menu = Backbone.View.extend({
    _someNumber: 0,
    _items: [],

    initialize: function () {
      this._someNumber++;
      //this._items = []; // uncommenting this creates a new array, rather than the reference to the class's
    },

    addItem: function (item) {
        this._items.push(item);
    }
});

var menu1 = new Menu();
menu1.addItem({foo: 'bar'});

console.log(menu1._items.length, menu1._someNumber);
$('#result1').text('Menu #1 Item count: ' + menu1._items.length + ' - someNumber: ' + menu1._someNumber);

var menu2 = new Menu();
menu2.addItem({foo: 'bar'});

console.log(menu1._items.length, menu1._someNumber);
$('#result2').text('Menu #1 Item count: ' + menu1._items.length + ' - someNumber: ' + menu1._someNumber);
```

So I guess my question would be - is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Is it on purpose that you use `menu1` in the second `console.log`

Comment: The short answer is yes, this is expected behavior. If you want your view instances to have their *own* array you can create it in the initialize method (like your commented out code). Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9975904/384985

Comment: @cr0 Yes - I was highlighting the fact that `menu1` contains 2 items even though `addItem()` is only called on `menu1` once

Comment: @muistooshort Looks like it